# Multiple CompletionService for one thread pool Java

Tags: java, concurrency, completion-service

I'm working on a Java server application with the general following architecture:

- Clients make RPC requests to the server
- The RPC server (gRPC) I believe has its own thread pool for handling requests
- Requests are immediately inserted into `Thread Pool 1` for more processing
- A specific request type, we'll call `Request R`, needs to run a few asynchronous tasks in parallel, judging the results to form a consensus that it will return to the client. These tasks are a bit more long running, so I use a separate `Thread Pool 2` to handle these requests. Importantly, each `Request R` will need to run the same 2-3 asynchronous tasks. `Thread Pool 2` therefore services ALL currently executing `Request R`'s. However, a `Request R` should only be able to see and retrieve the asynchronus tasks that belong to it.
- To achieve this, upon every incoming `Request R`, while its in `Thread Pool 1`, it will create a new `CompletionService` for the request, backed by `Thread Pool 2`. It will submit 2-3 async tasks, and retrieve the results. These should be strictly isolated from anything else that might be running in `Thread Pool 2` belonging to other requests.
- My questions:

  - Firstly, is Java's `CompletionService` isolated? I couldn't find good documentation on this after checking the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html). In other words, if two or more `CompletionService`'s are backed by the *same* thread pool, are any of them at risk of pulling a future belonging to another `CompletionService`?
  - Secondly, is this bad practice to be creating this many `CompletionService`'s for each request? Is there a better way to handle this? Of course it would be a bad idea to create a new thread pool for each request, so is there a more canonical/correct way to isolate futures within a `CompletionService` or is what I'm doing okay?

Thanks in advance for the help. Any pointers to helpful documentation or examles would be greatly appreciated.

Code, for reference, although trivial:

```java
public static final ExecutorService THREAD_POOL_2 =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(16, 64, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());

// Gets created to handle a RequestR, RequestRHandler is run in Thread Pool 1
public class RequestRHandler {

    CompletionService<String> cs;

    RequestRHandler() {
        cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(THREAD_POOL_2);
    }

    String execute() {
        cs.submit(asyncTask1);
        cs.submit(asyncTask2);
        cs.submit(asyncTask3);

       // Lets say asyncTask3 completes first
      Future<String> asyncTask3Result = cs.take();

      // asyncTask3 result indicates asyncTask1 & asyncTask2 results don't matter, cancel them
      // without checking result


      // Cancels all futures, I track all futures submitted within this request and cancel them,
      // so it shouldn't affect any other requests in the TP 2 pool
      cancelAllFutures(cs);


      return asyncTask3Result.get();  
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, is Java's `CompletionService` isolated?

That's not garanteed as it's an interface, so the implementation decides that. But as the only implementation is `ExecutorCompletionService` I'd just say the answer is: yes. Every instance of `ExecutorCompletionService` has internally a `BlockingQueue` where the finished tasks are queued. Actually, when you call `take` on the service, it just passes the call to the queue by calling `take` on it. Every submitted task is wrapped by another object, which puts the task in the queue when it's finished. So each instance manages it's submitted tasks isolated from other instances.

> Secondly, is this bad practice to be creating this many `CompletionService`s for each request?

I'd say it's okay. A `CompletionService` is nothing but a rather thin wrapper around an executor. You have to live with the "overhead" (internal `BlockingQueue` and wrapper instances for the tasks) but it's small and you are probably gaining way more from it than it costs. One could ask if you need one for just 2 to 3 tasks but it kinda depends on the tasks. At this point it's a question about if a `CompletionService` is worth it in general, so that's up to you to decide as it's out of scope of your question.